# How to put a filter in facebook places graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using this API request to fetch all the FITNESS_RECREATION centres using facebook places api.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&q=FITNESS_RECREATION&fields=name,location&limit=5&access_token=API_ID|SECRET_KEY

I am trying to do two things : 
1) To filter and get the request for which country = Malaysia.
2) To get a list of at least 5000 returns. Facebook seems to be restricting the response to a max of 100. Is there any workaround for this.

This is a sample response :

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Recreation Fitness",
         "location": {
            "city": "Long Beach",
            "country": "United States",
            "latitude": 33.833224817855,
            "longitude": -118.1849527359,
            "state": "CA",
            "street": "4234 Atlantic Ave",
            "zip": "90807"
         },
         "id": "420888681274648"
      },
      {
         "name": "Extreme Fitness- West Coast Recreation",
         "location": {
            "city": "Singapore",
            "country": "Singapore",
            "latitude": 1.30975,
            "longitude": 103.764183,
            "street": "12 West Coast Walk \u0040 West Coast Recreation",
            "zip": "127157"
         },
         "id": "982344108463873"
      },
      {
         "name": "TMP Fitness Sports and Recreation Club",
         "location": {
            "city": "Singapore",
            "country": "Singapore",
            "latitude": 1.3196699,
            "longitude": 103.84262,
            "street": "55 Newton Road, #05-02 Revenue House",
            "zip": "307987"
         },
         "id": "336128976479984"
      },
      {
         "name": "Fitness First Platinum Trinoma",
         "location": {
            "city": "Quezon City",
            "country": "Philippines",
            "latitude": 14.654392396144,
            "located_in": "322295778137",
            "longitude": 121.03377838573,
            "street": "North Ave"
         },
         "id": "516897225075490"
      },
      {
         "name": "Launceston PCYC Weight Gym, Fitness & Recreation Centre",
         "location": {
            "city": "Newstead",
            "country": "Australia",
            "latitude": -41.44732,
            "longitude": 147.15653,
            "state": "TAS",
            "street": "146 Abbott St",
            "zip": "7250"
         },
         "id": "169928146489153"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "after": "NAZDZD"
      },
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/search?access_token=737434766443796\u00257Cb10e3ea49284dc815b25910e6fb39aea&pretty=1&fields=name\u00252Clocation&q=FITNESS_RECREATION&type=place&limit=5&after=NAZDZD"
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried to use this format to filter for country = Malaysia :

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&q=FITNESS_RECREATION&fields=name,location{country=Malaysia}&limit=5000&access_token=APP_ID|secret_key



However, got the error : 

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (country=Malaysia) on node type (Location)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "DfofQreXq/8"
   }
}

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to do two things : 1) To filter and get the request for which country = Malaysia.

Not possible.

You can search for places around a given GEO location (using `center` and `distance` parameters, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search)

Or you can add `Malaysia` to the `name` you are searching for, to get places that actually have the country in their name.

More than that - not possible. You'd have to do additional filtering on your end.

> 2) To get a list of at least 5000 returns. Facebook seems to be restricting the response to a max of 100. Is there any workaround for this.

No, there is not, that is a deliberate limitation. You need to use paging to get more results. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

---

Just FYI, in case that should not be clear: Facebook provides the search endpoint, so that your app can perform a search in the name of the user, for a specific piece of information they might need at that time. It is not meant as a way for any app to get/"download" a complete set of data for a given search term to use for their own purposes.